# Adding Multiple Rect per data element in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using d3, I am trying to write a script to visualize the size of a number by showing it composed of individual blocks . So the number 5 would be composed of 5 rectangle. The general syntax to create rectangles within the svg is something as follows.

```
var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data([5, 3, 10])
    .enter()
    .append("rect) 
    ...
```

However, what I really want is something that append multiple rectangles per data element.

```
var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data([5, 3, 10])
    .enter()
    .do(CreatedRectangles(d))
```

Anyone know how to do this easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) and [`d3.range()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_range) for this:

```
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data([5,3,10])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.range(d); })
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(String);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5uLrj/).

You can use your `.do()` as well, except that it's called [`.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each). `CreateRectangle()` would look something like this.

```
function CreateRectangle(d) {
  d3.select(this).selectAll("p").data(d3.range(d)).enter().append("p").html(String);
}
```

It works similarly with SVG and `rect` elements.