# Fill D3.js rect with multiple colors or split rect into multiple rects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Goal: Create a grid where the X axis contains job titles and the Y axis has Part Numbers for each of the jobs. If a job requires more than one of a certain part number it will split the cell vertically into 2/3/4/5... different cells but still fit in the same row/column.

Problem: I am having trouble appending multiple rects for certain data points. I tried using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098230/adding-multiple-rect-per-data-element-in-d3) but had no luck. I tried using a for each loop with no luck as well. Any suggestion?

Current Progress:

[image]

Goal:

[image]

Code snippet in question:

```
    dayOffset = dayFormat(dateExtent[0]);
                rect = heatmap.selectAll('rect')
                  .data(data)
                .enter().append('rect')
                  .attr('width', function (d) {
                      return Xcellscale/d.NumberofPart;
                  })
                  .attr('height', Ycellscale)
                  .attr('x', function (d) {
                      return xAxisScale(d.JobNumber);
                  })
                  .attr('y', function (d) {
                      return yAxisScale(d.PartNumber);
                  })
                  .attr('fill', '#000FF0');
```

JSON:

```
{
        "data": [
          {
              "PartNumber": "a",
              "JobNumber": "a",
              "NumberofPart": "2",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T00:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 30.22
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "b",
              "JobNumber": "b",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T01:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 41.61
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "c",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T02:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 50.71
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "d",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T02:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 50.71
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "e",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T02:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 50.71
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "f",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T02:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 50.71
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "g",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T02:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 1000.71
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "h",
              "JobNumber": "c",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T03:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 250.34
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "i",
              "JobNumber": "d",
              "NumberofPart": "1",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T04:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 79.64
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "j",
              "JobNumber": "e",
              "NumberofPart": "2",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-25T05:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 76.93
              }
          },
          {
              "PartNumber": "k",
              "JobNumber": "f",
              "NumberofPart": "2",
              "timestamp": "2014-09-30T06:00:00",
              "value": {
                  "PM2.5": 106.45
              }
          }
        ]
    }
```

Here is all my code. It's based off of this [D3.js Example](http://bl.ocks.org/oyyd/859fafc8122977a3afd6) and sorry about the extra code I haven't removed regarding the timestamps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //UI configuration
    var itemSize = 18,
        cellSize = itemSize - 1,
        width = 800,
        height = 800,
        margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 25 };

    //formats
    var hourFormat = d3.time.format('%H'),
        dayFormat = d3.time.format('%j'),
        timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%X'),
        monthDayFormat = d3.time.format('%m.%d');

    //data vars for rendering
    var dateExtent = null,
        data = null,
        dayOffset = 0,
        colorCalibration = ['#00ff00', '#0033cc', '#ffcc00', '#ff6600', '#ff0000', '#9E0142'],
        dailyValueExtent = {};

    data = jsondata.data;

    //axises and scales
    var axisWidth = 0,
        axisHeight = itemSize * 24,
        xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d["JobNumber"]; }))
        .rangePoints([0, width]);
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xAxisScale)
        .orient('top'),
        yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d["PartNumber"]; }))
        .rangePoints([0, width]),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yAxisScale)
        .orient('left');


    initCalibration();

    var svg = d3.select('[role="heatmap"]');
    var heatmap = svg
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
        .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
    var rect = null;


        data.forEach(function (valueObj) {
            valueObj['date'] = timeFormat.parse(valueObj['timestamp']);


        });

        dateExtent = d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        });

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .call(xAxis)
        .append('text')
            .text('JobNumber')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + axisWidth + ',-10)');

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
            .text('PartNumber')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,' + axisHeight + ') rotate(-90)');

    //render heatmap rects


        Xcellscale = width / (xAxisScale.domain().length -1);
        Ycellscale = height / (yAxisScale.domain().length - 1);

        console.log(Xcellscale + " " + Ycellscale);
        console.log(width + " " + height);
        console.log(xAxisScale.domain().length + " " + data.map(function (d) { return d["PartNumber"]; }).length);

        dayOffset = dayFormat(dateExtent[0]);
        rect = heatmap.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
        .enter().append('rect')
            .attr('width', function (d) {
                return Xcellscale/d.NumberofPart;
            })
            .attr('height', Ycellscale)
            .attr('x', function (d) {
                return xAxisScale(d.JobNumber);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
                return yAxisScale(d.PartNumber);
            })
            .attr('fill', '#000FF0');

        rect.filter(function (d) { return d.value['PM2.5'] > 0; })
            .append('title')
            .text(function (d) {
                return monthDayFormat(d.date) + ' ' + d.value['PM2.5'];
            });

        //renderColor();


    function initCalibration() {
        d3.select('[role="calibration"] [role="example"]').select('svg')
            .selectAll('rect').data(colorCalibration).enter()
        .append('rect')
            .attr('width', cellSize)
            .attr('height', cellSize)
            .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                return i * itemSize;
            })
            .attr('fill', function (d) {
                return d;
            });

        //bind click event
        d3.selectAll('[role="calibration"] [name="displayType"]').on('click', function () {
            renderColor();
        });
    }

    function renderColor() {
        var renderByCount = document.getElementsByName('displayType')[0].checked;

        rect
            .attr('width', function (d) {
                return Xcellscale / d.NumberofPart;
            })
            .filter(function (d) {
                return (d.value['PM2.5'] >= 0);
            })
            .transition()
            .delay(function (d) {
                return 1;
            })
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween('fill', function (d, i, a) {
                //choose color dynamicly      
                var colorIndex = d3.scale.quantize()
                .range([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
                .domain(( [0, 500]));

                return d3.interpolate(a, '#00ff00');
            })

    }

    //extend frame height in `http://bl.ocks.org/`
    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "600px");
});
```

Comment: you can fill a rect with two colours via a linearGradient with 4 stops, one at the beginning, 2 identical stops in the middle and one at the end.

Comment: is there a way to increase the amount of stops with a linearGradient?

Comment: You can have as many as you want and add them dynamically too either via the DOM directly or using d3

Comment: lets say I want to add them within the rendercolor function. I'm still getting the hang of D3 and I am not sure how dynamically add attributes to an object like rect when I only now how to get the property through .attr('attribute', function (d) { return d.property}); The amount of attributes I want to add are in that property.

is there another way I can get something like   heatmap.selectAll('rect')
                .data(data)
            .enter(function (d) { for(i=0;i<d.number;i++)
                .append('rect')});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out. This isn't the most eloquent way of getting data onto the heat map but it works pretty well. Rather than using selectall().data().enter() I just used a for loop through my data set and appended the rectangles that way. I usually see people using a mapping function instead of a for loop so if there is any problems that might be caused by that let me know so I can improve my code.

Here is my Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    numberofparts = data[i].NumberofPart;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].NumberofPart; j++) {

        heatmap.append('rect')
        .attr('width', Xcellscale / numberofparts)
        .attr('height', Ycellscale)
        .attr('x', xAxisScale(data[i].JobNumber) + (j*(Xcellscale / numberofparts)))
        .attr('y', yAxisScale(data[i].PartNumber))
        .attr('fill', function () {
            if (j == 1) {
                return '#000FF0';
            }
            else
                return '#00000'
        });

    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my chart/heatmap now:

[image]

I hope this might help some people trying to do the same thing.

**UPDATE 6/16/2016**
Thanks Will and Robert with your help I improved my code using the .each() function and hopefully that will help me avoid problems that could occur using the for loop. I also referred to this example from [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/milroc/4254604) for help.

My updated code (I renamed a bunch of variables from the json as well):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/api/?????")
    .done(function (materialdata) {

        //UI configuration
        var itemSize = 18,
            cellSize = itemSize - 1,
            width = 2500,
            height = 15000,
            margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 100 };

        data = materialdata.ChartData;


        //axises and scales
        var axisWidth = 0,
            axisHeight = itemSize * 24,
            xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d["JobOrderNumber"]; }))
            .rangePoints([0, width]);
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xAxisScale)
            .orient('top'),
            yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(materialdata.Domain)
            .rangePoints([0, height]),
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yAxisScale)
            .orient('left');

        var svg = d3.select('[role="heatmap"]');
        var heatmap = svg
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
            .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
            .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
        var rect = null;

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .call(xAxis)
        .append('text')
            .text('')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + axisWidth + ',-10)');

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
            .text('')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,' + axisHeight + ') rotate(-90)');

        Xcellscale = (width / (xAxisScale.domain().length - 1)) - 1;
        Ycellscale = (height / (yAxisScale.domain().length - 1)) - 1;

        rect = heatmap.selectAll('svg')
            .data(data)
        .enter();

        rect.append('svg').each(function (d, i) {
            numberofparts = d.PartQuantity;
            for (var j = 0; j < d.PartQuantity; j++) {
                d3.select(this).append('rect')
                .attr('width', Xcellscale / numberofparts)
                .attr('height', Ycellscale)
                .attr('x', xAxisScale(d.JobOrderNumber) + (j * (Xcellscale / numberofparts)))
                .attr('y', yAxisScale(d.PartNumber))
                .attr('fill', function () {
                    return GetPartfromQuantities(materialdata, data[i].PartNumber);
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Here is how it looks now. I added more data to the set and added a coloring scheme.

[image: I added more data an colors to the chart]

Comment: I have worked on similar problems and had success using `.each()`, and then `d3.select(this)` in the function that you are `.each`ing. I think of it as "nesting" d3. My concern with your solution is that without using `.data().enter()`, you are not linking your data to your nodes, which might cause trouble later. Don't have time to write a full solution now, but let me know if you're still interested.

Comment: Definitely, I would love to see how you would do it with nesting. That sounds like a much better tactic and probably useful for when I might be dealing with a data set that might be more like a tree. I'll leave the topic unanswered for a while because your idea sounds like the best answer to me. I'll also check out the .each() method in the mean time.

Comment: I just ran across this article by Mike Bostock that might be helpful: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Comment: My blog is a work-in-progress, but here is a post related to your question: [http://www.wdickerson.com/blog/nestingd3/](http://www.wdickerson.com/blog/nestingd3/)  Turns out to be much simpler than using `.each()`

Comment: thanks for the example. I just have one question. Your function var   stationColors = 
        stationSymbols.selectAll("stationColors")
                      .data(function(d){return d.colors;}); involves another array like this  "colors":["blue","red","green","brown"] and I'm trying to do something with "numberofparts":3, how do you modify the code to use a parameter and not an array.